# rxjs operator informs me only if all concat observables complete

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

Say I have an http call to put /cart api, but for some reason our backend doesn't return an updated cart, instead, it returns 'success' string. So for getting an updated cart, I need to get /cart again to see new cart. What's the best way to do that?

following nested subscribes work but not good, since I don't want to do this every component:

```
http.put('/cart', data).subscribe(()=>{http.get('/cart').subscribe(()=>{/**update local cart*/})})
```

and I tried concat but it emits value for each http call

```
http.put('/cart', data).concat(http.get('/cart')).subscribe(/**update local*/)
```

this has a problem: if PUT success, but GET failed, the `/**update local*/` part still get invoked. That's not expected because I can't update local cart at that time.

I want the subscribe next section get called only when both previous observable completed, if error happens, go to error section

Answer (score 3):

You should always try to avoid nesting `subscribe` calls because you can't effectively handle error states (apart from making the Rx chain very hard to understand).

```
http.put('/cart', data)
  .concatMap(() => http.get('/cart'))
  .subscribe(
    cart => { /** update local */ }),
    error => { /** one of the HTTP calls failed */ },
  );
```

Note that I used `concatMap` instead of `concat` because with `concat` you're creating the HTTP call immediately when `concat` subscribes to it. Actually, the `concat` operator subscribes to inner Observables only after its source Observable completed so it will work as well but I'd still recommend using `concatMap` because it makes it obvious that you want to subscribe only after the previous Observable completed.

If you use `concatMap` its callback will be invoked only after the previous HTTP call emitted a value (which happens always only once with `http.put`).

Answer (score 1):

```
http.put('/cart', data)
    .switchMap(() => http.get<Cart>('/cart'))
    .subscribe(/**update local*/)
```